# get information from web page

Tags: python, html, search

i want to make script to get information from web page the information first that is page http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=74.125.232.147?showDetails=true&showARIN=false

so i want to get the `NetRange` and `Name` and `CIDR` ,so i made this code

```
import sys,urllib,re
J="http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=74.125.232.147?showDetails=true&showARIN=false"
A=urllib.urlopen(J)
AB=A.read()
A.close()
B=re.match("NetRange",AB)
print B
```

and it's not print out the information ;(

Answer (score 4):

B is a re match object. What you actually want is the value of the table cell next to the one that says `"NetRange"`. For that, you can use an HTML/XML parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Also, a note on style since the fact that this is homework suggests you're new to programming: Meaningful variable names are worth the effort it takes to type them out.

Comment: +1 for "Meaningful variable names are worth the effort it takes to type them out."

Comment: sir nmichaels can we do that script without soup module ?

Comment: @jack-X: It can certainly be done, but that's beyond the scope of this answer. Just be warned that parsing XML with regular expressions will get you a lot of "don't do that" comments.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to revisit what you're searching for, because it's not even in the data that is returned.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> J="http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=74.125.232.147?showDetails=true&showARIN=false"
>>> resp = urllib.urlopen(J)
>>> resp.code
200
>>> data = resp.read()
>>> 'NetRange' in data
>>> False
```

Additionally, look over the documentation for [Python's re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), specifically the section on [search() vs. match()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match). In this case you want `search()`, not `match()`.

Comment: thanks guys but i want to print the `NetRange` so i don't know how !,thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

That regular expression is woefully inadequate, unfortunately. You should copy and paste the **XML** source of that page into a text editor and examine it. First, recognize that it's XML styled by XSLT. Have you covered XML in your class? If so, you should know that you need to use a proper XML parser, like [elementtree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to make this much easier, better and more reliable.

If for some reason you **must** do this as a regular expression (really, don't unless it's a class requirement) you need to modify your approach. Perhaps put it in [re-try](http://re-try.appspot.com/) to help develop your regex. At the very least you're going to need parenthesis to capture the values. Here's an example for a different piece of website, http://api.hostip.info/?ip=4.8.42.19

```
countryMatches = re.findall(r"""<countryName>(.+)</countryName>""", AB)
if countryMatches:
    country = countyMatches.group(0)[0] #first match, first (only) group)
```

Also, please use better variable names. One letter is really terrible style. Your code is hard to read, and will only get harder as it does more work.